# Typescript Type for Array of Objects with different Types

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I'm trying to write the type for an array that contains objects, but with different types.

```
[
        {
            "id": "test",
            "answer": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "test_multi",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": "skill_1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "skill_2"
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

My first approaches were:

```
prop: { id: string; answer: string | boolean | { id: string; answers: { id: string }[]} }[];
```

I guess in this case I'm assigning the different object to the **answer** prop.

Next approach

```
    { id: string; answer: string | boolean;  } | { id: string; answers: { id: string }[] }[];
```

But in this case I guess I'm not allowing the array to be filled by the first type of object.

How can I write the type for "this array can contain this object AND/OR this object"?

Comment: Your second approach is close, just use parentheses `( ... )` from the beginning until the `[]`

Comment: Or `Array<Foo | Bar>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parentheses like this:

```
({ id: string; answer: string | boolean;  } | { id: string; answers: { id: string }[] })[];
```

Comment: WOOHOO!! Thanks!! 
P.s.: I have to wait 9 minutes before I can accept your answer

Comment: I would also recommend adding interfaces or type aliases, this is unwieldy.

Comment: @PaulB I believe you've waited more than 9 minutes  anyways, I'm glad it helped you're l you. And as H.B. said, it's a good idea to break it down into type aliases or interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the input. It would be hard to work with different variants of 'answer'/'answer'.

You can make something like that:

```
type Answer = string | boolean;
interface TestItem {
    id: string;
    answer?: Answer | Array<TestItem>;
}

const results: TestItem[] = [
        {
            "id": "test",
            "answer": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "test_multi",
            "answer": [
                {
                    "id": "skill_1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "skill_2"
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

If you want to stay with 'answers', then try this:

```
type Answer = string | boolean;
interface TestItem {
    id: string;
    answer?: Answer;
    answers?: Array<TestItem>;
}

const results: TestItem[] = [
        {
            "id": "test",
            "answer": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "test_multi",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "id": "skill_1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "skill_2"
                }
            ]
        },
]
```